# Get a line segment on the line parallel to another line segment

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have 3 points. A and B and a C. I want the line segment throu C, parallel to the line on which A and B are.

[image: line segment image]

In the image above I want the `A'` and `B'` points.

I know I can get the slope of the line between `A` and `B` and get the line passing through `C` with the `y = mx + b` formula. But I'm not sure how to get the `A'` and `B'` points.

#### Edit

Sorry I didn't give any information about the `A'` and `B'` points. Basically they're the same points on the new line segment if we map every point to the new line. This means that `A'` is a point on the new line with the same distance as `C` from `AB`'s line. Sorry if there's a word in geometry for this. English is not my native language.

Comment: Why do you want the points $A'$ and $B'$? If you get a line on the form $y=kx+b$ you're done right? What really do you even mean by the points $A'$ and $B'$? Are they the orthogonal projection on to the line through $C$?

Comment: @OveAhlman Added an edit. Hopefully this will clear what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a line through $(x_A,y_A)$ and $(x_B,y_B)$ is

$$A \mathbf{x} + B \mathbf{y} + C=0\\(y_B-y_A) \mathbf{x} + (x_A-x_B) \mathbf{y} + x_B y_A - x_A y_B = 0 $$

The equation of parallel passing through $(x_C,y_C)$ is

$$A \mathbf{x} + B \mathbf{y} + C'=0 \\(y_B-y_A) \mathbf{x} + (x_A-x_B) \mathbf{y} + y_C (x_B-x_A) + x_C (y_A-y_B) = 0 $$

The point on the parallel a line $A \mathbf{x} + B \mathbf{y} + C' = 0$ closest to point $(x_A,y_A)$ is

$$ (x_A',y_A') = \left( \frac{B^2 x_A-A (B y_A+C')}{A^2+B^2},\; \frac{A^2 y_A-B (A x_A+C')}{A^2+B^2} \right) $$

and similarly for the other point

$$ (x_B',y_B') = \left( \frac{B^2 x_B-A (B y_B+C')}{A^2+B^2},\; \frac{A^2 y_B-B (A x_B+C')}{A^2+B^2} \right) $$

with

$$\begin{align} A & = y_B-y_A = -13\\ B & = x_A-x_B = -25 \\ C & = x_B y_A - x_A y_B = 630 \\ C' & = y_C (x_B-x_A) + x_C (y_A-y_B) = 406 \end{align} $$

$$ (x_A',y_A') = \left( \frac{2514}{397}, \; \frac{5140}{397} \right) = (6.33, 12.95) $$
$$ (x_B',y_B') = \left( \frac{12439}{397}, \; -\frac{21}{397} \right) = (31.33, -0.05)$$

Confirmation with Geogebra

[image: pic]

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. Very clear and through.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice,

the equation of line segment $A'B'$ passing through the point $C(12, 10)$ & parallel to the line passing through the points $A(10, 20)$ & $B(35, 7)$ is given as $$y-10=\frac{20-7}{10-35}(x-12)$$
$$y=\frac{-13}{25}x+\frac{406}{25}$$
Now, in order to get the foots of perpendicular points $A'$ & $B'$ from the points $A(10, 20)$ & $B(35, 7)$ on the line $A'B'$ 
Let the point $A'$ be $(a, b)$. Since the line $A'B'$ $\perp$  $AA'$ hence $$\frac{b-20}{a-10}\times \frac{-13}{25}=-1$$ $$25a-13b=-10\tag 1$$
Since, the point $A'(a, b)$ lies on the line $A'B'$ hence satisfying the equation of line $A'B'$ by the point $A'(a, b)$ we get $$13a+25b=406\tag 2$$
Now, solving (1) & (2), we get $$a=\frac{2514}{397}, \ b=\frac{5140}{397}$$
Hence, the point $A'$ is $\color{red}{\left(\frac{2514}{397}, \frac{5140}{397}\right)}$

I hope you can find out the coordinates of point $B'$ which is the reflection of point $B(35, 7)$ by following the similar method

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added an edit. I would appreciate it you could help me find the `A'` and `B'` points. Thanks.

Comment: Please see the updated image. I really don't know the distance from each section unless I can see the mapped point of C on the AB line. I don't have that information in my case.

Answer (score 1):

After getting green line parallel to blue line containing $A,B$ you have freedom  for $A'$ or $ B'$ to move anywhere on green line.

You have not given any clue how  to fix $A'$ or $ B'$ locations so their exact position cannot be determined.

EDIT1

Add 2 and subtract 10 for $ x,y $ co-ordinates respectively to come from A to A' or B to B' in new positions.

So A goes from $(10,20)  $ to $(12,10) $ and  B goes from $(35,7) $ to $( 37, -3). $

It is called parallel displacement or translation of straight line AB to A'B' in new position.  The lines $ AB, A'B', AA', BB' $ form a $ parallellogram.$

If you understood it please include the new position of B' in the new sketch. Present indication of B' is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added an edit. I would appreciate it you could help me find the `A'` and `B'` points. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate where the **2** **10** come from? I'll fix my sketch right away

Comment: Also, suppose the `C` point has the distance `d` to the line. Can I do this *Translation* in such way that I move get the new points with `d/2` distance instead of `d`? Basically I want to move the line segment (with the same slope) closer to the `C` with half the distance